# I had an issue with select group by logic utilizing QueryDSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

We are currently using QueryDSL to implement the SELECT logic.
For now, the code looks like this

```java
@Entity
class Answer(
    @Lob var content: String,
    @EmbeddedId val id: AnswerId,
) : BaseEntity() {
    constructor(content: String, questionId: Long, writerId: String) :
            this(content, AnswerId(questionId, writerId))

}


@Entity
class AnswerComment(
    @Lob var content: String,
    var commentWriterId: String,
    @Embedded val answer: AnswerId,
    @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long = 0L,
)


@Embeddable
data class AnswerId(
    val questionId: Long,
    val writerId: String
) : Serializable


data class AnswerRes @QueryProjection constructor(
    val content: String,
    val questionId: Long,
    val writer: MemberRes,
    val comments: List<AnswerCommentRes>
)

data class AnswerCommentRes @QueryProjection constructor(
    val id: Long,
    val content: String,
    val writer: MemberRes,
)
```

Here I want to write a query to retrieve a List.

So, I've configured the DAO logic as follows

```java
@Service
class AnswerDao(
    private val queryFactory: JPAQueryFactory,
) {
    fun findAllByQuestion(questionId: Long): List<AnswerRes> {
        return queryFactory
            .select(
                QAnswerRes(
                    answer.content,
                    answer.id.questionId,
                    QMemberRes(member.email, member.nickname),
                    GroupBy.list(
                        QAnswerCommentRes(
                            answerComment.id,
                            answerComment.content,
                            QMemberRes(member.email, member.nickname)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .from(answer, answerComment)
            .join(member).on(answer.id.writerId.eq(member.email))
            .join(member).on(answerComment.commentWriterId.eq(member.email))
            .where(answer.id.questionId.eq(questionId))
            .groupBy(answer.id)
            .fetch()
    }
}
```

This results in the following error.

```bash
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: SqmQualifiedJoin predicate referred to SqmRoot [`site.qbox.qboxserver.domain.answer.command.entity.Answer(answer)`] other than the join's root [`site.qbox.qboxserver.domain.member.command.entity.Member(member1)`]
```

What could be the cause and how can I fix it?
The AnswerRes should contain a List of AnswerCommentRes.
We also want to utilize Group BY rather than SubQuery.